# window.location not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I have an asp.net web form with an html input and button at the top that I need to use as a search box. I need to integrate the template for the page with a page written in php so I'm trying to write the search box code as compatible with asp.net and php as I can.

That being said, I don't want the button to be a submit button since I don't want it to interfere with any buttons that appear on the page below it that might have to be submit buttons themselves.

When I click the Go button, everything works as expected. A lot of users, myself included, prefer to just hit the enter button and assume it will click the Go button. Since it is not a submit button this will not do, however when I hit return in the textbox, even with code in the onkeydown to run the search/redirect function, all it does is refresh the page.

Search box/button:

```
<input onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) doSearch() " id="search" type="text" name="search" value="Search" style="width: 116px;" /><input id="btSearch" onclick="doSearch();" style="width: 33px; margin-left: 2px;" type="button" value="Go" />
```

Search function:

```
function doSearch() {
    var query = document.getElementById("search").value;
    window.location = "/Search.aspx?" + query;
}
```

What is intercepting my redirection to the search page when I hit enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the whole form?  The default action when you hit enter in a text field in most browsers is to submit the form, so your browser is submitting it after it calls the JS because your handler is not suppressing the default action.  Add a return false to do so:

```
<input onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {doSearch(); return false; }" id="search" type="text" name="search" value="Search" style="width: 116px;" /><input id="btSearch" onclick="doSearch();" style="width: 33px; margin-left: 2px;" type="button" value="Go" />
```

Alternatively, just put the correct `ACTION` value in the `form` tag - otherwise the form will not work for users who do not have JavaScript!

Comment: It's an ASP.NET form... I can't really alter the action of the form and leave the rest of the page working correctly, and I can't put a form in a form or it also breaks the asp.net form. Who, exactly, does not have JS capabilities these days? Thanks. This was the ticket.

Comment: I sometimes disable JS when I tether my laptop to my phone to stop excessive AJAX calls eating up my bandwidth.  I also sometimes use [lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)) which doesn't have JS.  Furthermore, I have recently come across a client of my employer whose IT department are so paranoid that they've dissabled JS on all of their user's machines!

Comment: I understand that for security reasons one might turn it off, but really, aren't you turning "off" most of the usefulness of the web by doing so? I think 3/4 of my site would come across as an unordered blob of text if you did that.

Comment: Nope, as long as the underlying HTML doc is well-structured, it can be a breeze.  You really ought to think of graceful degradation and be more considerate to irritating people like me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your forum is still being submitted. Add return false to cancel this:

```
<input onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) ( doSearch(); return false; )" id="search" type="text" name="search" value="Search" style="width: 116px;" /><input id="btSearch" onclick="doSearch(); return false;" style="width: 33px; margin-left: 2px;" type="button" value="Go" />
```

You could also do it in an onsubmit handler to handle both with one call.

Comment: I've tried that. Adding "return false;" where you've indicated results in no text being typed in the input box. It cancels all input.

Comment: You need curly braces after the `if` condition:  `if (event.keyCode == 13) { doSearch(); return false; }`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice. Fixed.